# Merge columns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2017 have a stored procedure where I have a simple select with joins like:

```
SELECT
      [p].[legacyKey] AS JobNumber
    , [p].[Name] AS JobName
    , [G].[Label] AS DesignStatus
    , [GS].[Description]  AS ShopStatus
    , [JN].Title
    , [JN].Note
    , 'Remove' AS [Remove]
      FROM [Project] AS [P]
          INNER JOIN [Customer] AS [c] ON [P].[CustomerSoldById] = [C].[CustomerKey]
          INNER JOIN [General] AS [G] ON [P].[StatusKey] = [G].[GeneralKey]
          INNER JOIN [General] AS [GS] ON [P].[ShopsStatus] = [GS].[GeneralKey]
          INNER JOIN ProjectDesign AS PD ON P.ProjectKey = PD.ProjectKey
          INNER JOIN DESIGN AS D ON PD.DesignKey = D.DesignKey
          INNER JOIN JobNotes AS JN ON PD.DesignKey = JN.DesignKey
      WHERE [G].[Extended] = 'Project Status'
      and p.LegacyKey = 18213
```

result of this query is:

```
+-----------+----------+--------------+------------+--------+-------------------+--------+
| JobNumber | JobNAme  | DesignStatus | ShopStatus | Title  |       Note        | Remove |
+-----------+----------+--------------+------------+--------+-------------------+--------+
|      1234 | TestName | Correct      | Inc        | Title1 | Note test design  | Remove |
|      1234 | TestName | Correct      | Inc        | Title2 | note test proyect | Remove |
+-----------+----------+--------------+------------+--------+-------------------+--------+
```

As you can see all columns are exactly the same except for `Title` and `Note` columns, is it possible to merge Title and Note  to get only one column instead two?, Example :

```
+-----------+----------+--------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--+
| JobNumber | JobNAme  | DesignStatus | ShopStatus |                             Note                             | Remove |  |
+-----------+----------+--------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--+
|      1234 | TestName | Correct      | Inc        | Title1 : Note test design \n , Title2 : note test proyect \n | Remove |  |
+-----------+----------+--------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--+
```

I try

```
CONCAT([JN].[Title], ': ', STRING_AGG([JN].[Note], '\N'))
```

But it just concat `title` column with `note` column but it no merge row 1 with row 2, what am I doing wrong? Regards

Comment: You can do this easily with SQL Server 2017 and later, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql

Comment: This is called a PIVOT. Search this site for `sql-server PIVOT` or `sql-server rows to column` for many existing examples.

Comment: concat title, " : ", and note then string_agg() that column. If your version is before 2017 then concat and take a look at stuff() function for xml path

Comment: I'm using 2017, I will check  string_agg() to solve this @HenningKoehler

Comment: As your comment I try , `CONCAT([JN].[Title], ': ', STRING_AGG([JN].[Note], '\N'))`, but it just concat Title with note and its correct but it no merge row 1 with row 2 values  @user8834780

Comment: @Jonathan as stated, after concat, use string_agg()- that will merge row 1 with row 2. Simpler than the solution below using stuff(), which assumes a pre-2017 version

Comment: As my update in question I try it as: `CONCAT([JN].[Title], ': ', STRING_AGG([JN].[Note], '\N'))` But it just concat title column with note column but it no merge row 1 with row 2 @user8834780

Comment: @Jonathan you need to wrap the concatenated field in string_agg(). See answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `concat()` then `string agg()`:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=69806c24356e5ef86fd0bfa7a239c82b

Edit 1:
If you don't want the `/n` for the last value in the string, you can do:

`select left(string,len(string)-3) 
from (
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(Title, ': ', Note, ' \n'),', ') as string
from test
) t`

Edit 2: 
If you have multiple job numbers and don't want all values to aggregate to one row, you can do:

`select left(string,len(string)-3) 
from (
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(Title, ': ', Note, ' \n'),', ') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY JobNumber) as string
from test
group by JobNumber
) t`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are expecting by using a dynamic query to 'pivot' columns to rows and then you can use it in a grouped by query to return without duplicates.
Here's the code from your example. I replaced your query for your results inserted in a table but you can use it to replace my test table to test it in more, different results.

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
JobNumber int
,JobNAme varchar(25)
,DesignStatus varchar(25)
,ShopStatus varchar(25)
,Title varchar(25)
,Note varchar(50)
,Remove varchar(25)
)

GO

INSERT INTO test(JobNumber,JobNAme,DesignStatus,ShopStatus,Title,Note,Remove)
VALUES
(1234,'TestName','Correct','Inc','Title1','Note test design','Remove')
,(1234,'TestName','Correct','Inc','Title2','Note test proyect','Remove')

GO

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + title + ': ' + Note + ' \n' 
            FROM test 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT JobNumber,JobNAme,DesignStatus,ShopStatus,'''+@Cols+''' AS Note,Remove 
    FROM test
)
SELECT  JobNumber,JobNAme,DesignStatus,ShopStatus,NOTE,Remove 
FROM CTE
GROUP BY JobNumber,JobNAme,DesignStatus,ShopStatus,NOTE,Remove '
--PRINT @query
EXEC sp_executesql @query
```