# using stored procedure i need leavetype should be horizontally in sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, pivot

using stored procedure output given below but I need leavetype should be horizontally in sql server 2014.

[image]

I need output like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code here? We need the code to be able to reproduce in our laptops to be able to solve it, and picture don't help us with that. If you provide us the code to create a sample table with the data to populate it, it would be great.

You will need to pivot the rows to columns and put the name LeaveType value in the column name. 
You can solve your problem by using a pivot dynamic SQL. 
Since I don't have your code, I'm gonna send you something similar that I solved with that and you can try it there. With the column names modified by something similar to this query, you can pivot and get what you are expecting.

[Merge columns in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53549011/merge-columns-in-sql/53549669#53549669)

Comment: This should be a comment, because it does not answer the question. If you lack the reputation for comments, then first gather reputation. This will only hurt your rep because of the risk of downvotes.